# How to parse an expression to be used as a label (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a function to make a `ggplot2` graphic. In this function, I am passing a string as a variable that I would like to use as the y-label. To do so, I am using `parse()`. The following works fine:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ylab <- "xxx ~(x^2)"

plot_fun <- function(ylab) {
  ggplot() +
    ylab(parse(text = ylab))
}

plot_fun(ylab)
```

[image]

In the next example, I have an error because of the % sign.

```r
ylab <- "xxx ~(%)"
plot_fun(ylab)
#> Error in parse(text = ylab): <text>:1:7: unexpected input
#> 1: xxx ~(%)
#>           ^
```

Is there a *better* way to parse the string?

<sup>Created on 2020-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put backticks in between  the `"%"` the symbol :

```
ylab <- "xxx ~(`%`)"
plot_fun(ylab)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formating your labels with `expression()` if necessary:

```
ylab <- expression(xxx ~"(%)")
plot_fun(ylab)
```

Output:

[image]